# MySQL Regexp won't work

Tags: mysql, regex

I have the following query:

```
SELECT  `admin_users`.* 
FROM `admin_users` 
WHERE (avatar REGEXP 'avatars/Name-[0-9]+.jpg+')  
ORDER BY `admin_users`.`avatar` 
DESC LIMIT 1
```

It's ok if I have something like:

- `avatars/Name-5.jpg`
- `avatars/Name-6.jpg`

But if I have, `avatars/Name-15.jpg`, for example, it doesn't return in query.

In other words, It only works for 1 digit, not for more. How can I solve it?

Comment: It should work.  Why `g+` at the end?

Comment: I'd escape the dot: `'avatars/Name-[0-9]+\\.jpg'`. It must work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Why two slashes? I think one slash could be enough to escape the dot `avatars/Name-[0-9]+\.jpg`

Comment: If you're unsure, you can always use a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html): `SELECT 'avatars/Name-15.jpg' REGEXP 'avatars/Name-[0-9]+[.]jpg'` > **1**

Comment: Guys, thanks for the attempts, but escaping the dot don't help me. @bobblebubble your answer is correct, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When comparing strings (an that is what `avatar` is), "avatars/Name-1..." comes before "avatars/Name-5..." simply because the *string* "1" comes before "5".

It is not practical to order those by an embedded number.  This would do what you want, but it is pretty cryptic:

```
ORDER BY 0 + MID(avatar, 14)
```

**To explain**

1. MID will start at the 14th character of 'avatars/Name-15.jpg' and extract '15.jpg'.
2. 0+ will take that string, convert it to a number and deliver the *number* 15.  (When a string is turned into a number, the first characters are taken as long as it looks like a number.  So, `0+'abc'` will deliver `0`, since there is nothing at the beginning of `abc` that looks like a number.)

If the left part were not exactly 14 characters in all cases, the trick will fail.  And it may get so complicated as to be 'impossible' in SQL.

Comment: It works, thanks! Could you explain what `0 + MID(avatar, 14)` does?